# Comment owner should be notified if comment is flagged as obsolete (not otherwise)

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags, obsolete-information

Frequently, I suggest a post author to make a particular change.  The author makes the change, then notified me in a comment to inform me.  I delete my comment (which is now obsolete) and flag the other comment for being obsolete as well.  Then a *moderator* needs to come along, verify the comment is indeed obsolete, and delete it.

The moderator workload would be reduced significantly if the comment author was notified as well.  The comment author will probably have the conversation in fresh memory.